# How do you draw one shape under another in Java?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, custom-painting

I know how to draw shapes and stuff in Java and know that more recently-drawn shapes stack up on previously drawn shapes, but how do you draw one shape *under* another? Like let's say you filled a Rectangle() r1, but then filled another Rectangle() r2 and had it display under r1. How would one do that? Other than just redrawing r1 over r2?

Comment: You need to tell us which library you use, or best post [mcve] showing what you did. If you use [swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for example, `paintComponent` does exactly that: paints each shape over previously painted shapes.

Comment: I'm using Swing. I would have something like
`Graphics2D g2;
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(2, 2, 10, 10);
g2.fill(r1);
g2.fill(r2);`
using `paintComponent` but I was wondering if there were a way to draw `r2` under `r1` without redrawing `r1`. I didn't mention the library because I would switch libraries if I had to to draw one shape under another.

Comment: What did u try ? post your code.